# Word meaning "initial and annual"?

Tags: word-choice

In my business, we accept monthly payments however the first monthly payment is higher than the 11 following payments. When the service renews the next year we change the higher initial fee again. I want to say something like this:

> $20 per month after an initial payment of $100

But that makes it sound like the initial payment is a one-off, but it recurs annually when the policy is renewed.

Is there a more succinct way to say "initial but recurring"?

Comment: Initial cannot be recurring. Forget initial and stick with annual. It's quite a common practice to have "a monthly and an annual payment" *$20 monthly along with a $100 annual payment, (both payable at the beginning of the terms.*)

Comment: Do you want people to understand you (and consequently pay their *annual* fee), or do you want to save ink/space on the contract? To my mind, this is not a time to be *succinct*.

Comment: @medica People also need to be saved from having to read over-long sentences and from getting lost along the way.

Comment: that's an incredibly strange pricing model.  I can't think of any common way to explain that. **initial** is totally irrelevant, don't use it.  You'd have to say something like "a monthly fee of 20, and an annual fee of 100 charged each year in the month you commenced".   But it won't matter much as you won't have any customers ;-)  (Just teasing)

Comment: @JoeBlow In our industry this pricing model isn't uncommon. We broker a service and want our broker fee up front so if they cancel, we still make all our fee.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with $x with a $y initial/renewal payment

Comment: Sure, I understand.  (Believe me, I like charging customers :) )  It's definitely a difficult one to explain.  I'd probably literally say "There is a calendar monthly fee of $20 charged on the 15th of each calendar month. And there's an annual agency fee of $275 which is charged each year on your starting month."  Now, where I just wrote "agency fee" I'd try to pick the best description:  **administration fee, agency fee, brokerage fee, fuel-surcharge fee, trading fee, software fee, licensing fee** or so on.

Comment: Don't use "initial", at all - it's just wrong.

Comment: Here's a short version: "There is a repeating monthly fee of $25 and a repeating annual agency fee of $115.  Click here to accept our EULAs."

Comment: Every [month] you will be charged £100, and thereafter £20 per month.

Comment: Ild probably go with an “annual subscription fee” and a “monthly maintenance or access fee” or vice versa.  But really, consumers will be unhappy about this and will want a one-time “setup” fee followed by a fixed monthly fee and that’s it.  If you can’t live without the extra “January” money roll it into the average monthly fee.

Answer (score 2):

Contract includes a $20 monthly fee and $100 **annual renewal** [surcharge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/surcharge)

Contract includes a $20 monthly fee and $100 **yearly renewal** surcharge

Contract includes a $20 monthly fee and $100 **per annum** surcharge

Comment: These are completely confusing ......... because the concept is completely confusing!  :)  I think the key fact is "don't use initial in any way".

Comment: Saying "renewal" doesn't imply that there is going to be a higher initial payment because the first payment isn't a renewal.

Comment: @Coomie the use of the combination of annual/yearly/per annum *and* 'surcharge' is what indicates the 1.
an additional charge, tax, or cost.
2.
an excessive sum or price charged.
3.
an additional or excessive load or burden.

Answer (score 0):

I shall plagiarize from 3rd News' answer. Since, in the US, "surcharge" is such a big word, we normally use the word fee.

You have quite a few choices.

- There is an annual renewal fee of $50, besides the fee you pay every month.
- There is an annual setup fee of $50, besides the fee you pay every month.
- There is an annual service fee of $50, besides ....
- There is an annual membership fee of $50, besides ....
- .... annual maintenance fee  ....
- .... annual administrative fee  ....
- .... annual service continuance fee  ....

Just kiddin' ...

- annual money laundering fee
- annual police bribery cost
- annual obamacare-subsidy fee
- annual [zakat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakat)
- annual union's [hong bao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_bao)

Answer (score -1):

> *There is an annual cost of $100 for the first month of service,
>   followed by eleven monthly payments of $20. The cumulative annual cost is $320.*